# How to call an URL with php without redirect

Tags: php, curl, parameters, file-get-contents

I'm using an URL to transmit parameters to a remote location. 
I need to call the URL using PHP - without redirecting to the URL.

I've tried  different solutions without luck. I am no way near an expert when dealing with PHP, I am even unsure if I am wording the question correctly.

I've tried:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://remotelocation.com/storedata.aspx?name=".$name."&email=".$email_address.);
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

and:

```
file_get_contents("https://remotelocation.com/storedata.aspx?name=".$name."&email=".$email_address.")
```

without any luck.

Calling the URL manually in a browser (using definite values instead of variables) the data is stored. Using mail() instead the data is also transmitted.

I know the solution must be pretty simple. Can anyone help to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't the fact that you might be missing an equal sign after `name`? (eg `file_get_contents("https://remotelocation.com/storedata.aspx?name=".$name."&email=".$email_address.")`)

Comment: You're missing `=` behind name. Or is it a typo?

Comment: sorry.. it's a typo. Forgot when rewriting the link for the question... the "="'s are included in the tested code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't work with `file_get_contents`. But for curl you need to add the following  few options as well(There are a lot in fact, you can check it from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).

```
// to handle https links
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

// return response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

And to grab the returned response html

```
$response_html = curl_exec ($curl);
```